# Showing Bad parameter when I tried to export as csv file from phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, export-to-csv

The problem is that I want to export as CSV file from phpmyadmin. What I did before is, in phpMyAdmin > Under SQL tab, I pasted the query

```
Select distinct(a.barcode),a.blks,a.rows,a.cols,a.status,a.hw_type,a.g_event,b.product,a.dice,a.charac,a.flow,a.inout,a.drawn_no,a.touch_down,a.max_down,a.accu_touch,a.owner from pb_db.hardware_info as a inner join pb_db.product_hwevent as b on a.g_event=b.g_event where a.amksite='TPY' and b.pl in(19,66) AND a.status!='Transfer' ORDER BY `id` ASC;
```

and results are shown.

I scroll down to the bottom and click export and I chose `Quick` in export method. Format is `CSV`. After that When I click export, it shows `phpMyAdmin Error! Bad Parameter`. May I know why it is causing?

Comment: Fixed. I didn't select the database and try to export it. So that I got that error.